# Which $VARIABLES can be passed to an external tool from git-gui?

Tags: git, msysgit, git-gui

When I add a new tool to `git-gui`, the dialog indicates that I could use some variables to be passed to the tool (`$REVISION`, `$ARGS`, `$FILENAME`).

Are there any other parameters that are *not* documented (for example the current repo directory, etc.)? Why are they not contained in the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-gui) of the `git-gui`?

My current use case is that I have two scripts that enable/disable a pre-commit hook. Currently, I have to open my Windows Explorer and double-click the batch-files which is a bit clumsy. Easier way would be to do that directly out of `git-gui`...

As an alternative (side-question), I would also be interested in bypassing the pre-commit hook (i.e. pass `--no-verify` when committing) out of `git-gui`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking at the [`git-gui` sources](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/git-gui), I find (not present in [git-gui man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-gui)):

- [`git-gui.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-gui/git-gui.sh):

  - `$GITGUI_VERBOSE`, to enable verbose loading
  - `SSH_ASKPASS`, to suggest our implementation of askpass, if none is set
  - `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`, for repository setup

Comment: I see `set s "usage: $::argv0 $::subcommand $::subcommand_args"`: maybe there is a way to pass and execute a sub git command...

Comment: @eckes right, those are the variable taken into account by git-gui at launch time. However, `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` should still be set (`Tools --> Add`) and taken into account by the sub-command. I got nothing on the `--no-verify` though.

Answer (score 3):

I personal extended `git-gui` for having tools working on multiple files

In the `tools.tcl` file, add the following 2 lines

```
set env(GIT_GUITOOL) $fullname
set env(FILENAME) $current_diff_path
>> set env(FILENAMES) [array names selected_paths]
```

and :

```
unset env(GIT_GUITOOL)
unset env(FILENAME)
>> unset env(FILENAMES)
```

Use `$FILENAMES` instead of `$FILENAME` in your tool, and list of files will be passed on separated by spaces (very useful for creating a tool like : `rm $FILENAMES` )

Note on `$FILENAME` (and `$FILENAMES`)
Git gui tool mechanism doesn't work with files containing spaces
I tried quoting each file, by writing

```
set env(FILENAMES) [string map { \{ \" \} \" } [array names selected_paths]]
```

But `Console::exec` seems to separate args on space and escape each argument.

Comment: +1. sounds interesting, in addition of the variables I identified in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two notes to the previous solution:

1. global selected_paths

to post non empty $FILENAMES to the command it is neccessary to declare selected_paths as global

2. files containing spaces

to post files containing spaces use "${FILENAMES[@]}" instead of plain $FILENAMES.

You can see how the pathes are sent to a command by using command **printf     '\"%s\" '**
e.g.

printf '\"%s\" ' FILENAMES= "${FILENAMES[@]}"

Comment: I can't get ${FILENAMES[@]} to work - I get 
`sh: 1: Bad substitution`